# using Ajax Minfy To minify and compress files

Tags: javascript, iis

I was just checking out the ajax minfy tool http://ajaxmin.codeplex.com and used this to create a minified js file.It shows in the result the minified and then gzipped file content but I just wanted to make sure that the file is indeed gzipped ..How can I test that and also what happens if we have gzipping enabled in IIS but the file is already gzipped does IIS just renders the file without zipping it again or something else.

Comment: the browsers rely on server headers injected by IIS to tell them the compression algorithm used... if you compress a file without letting IIS do it and you don't have that header there it doesn't seem like it would work properly.

Comment: Got it ..and I did the checking by fiddler and it's gzipped but ur point is very valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use your favorite debugging tool for the webbrowser (like Firebug) and inspect the HTTP request. If the file was indeed successfully transmitted as a gzipped file, you will see a `Content-Encoding: gzip` header. It may also say `deflate`, which is more or less the same thing.